# The code uses for in a string, but I don't know what's wrong

Tags: python, string

I am trying to solve this, but I am not sure what is wrong with my code.
Can you tell me where is wrong?

If you just type one letter at a time, you will have to press the key for the length of `A`.

To speed it up a bit, some string B is stored, so you can type the entire `B` by pressing the key once.

It is not possible to erase already typed characters.

For example, when `A = ”asakusa”`, `B = ”sa”`, you can type `A` in `5` times by using `B` twice as shown in the following figure.

Given `A` and `B`, find the minimum number of times you have to press the key to type A in its entirety.

The first line is given the number `T` of test cases.

For each test case, two strings `A` and `B` are given on the first line. The length of `A` is `1` to `10,000`, and the length of `B` is `1` to `100`.

Input:

```
1
apple ap
```

Output:

```
1 4
```

Code:

```py
T = int(input())
for tc in range(1, T + 1):
    A, B = input().split()
    idx = 0
    cnt = 0
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    for i in range(N):
        if A[i] == B[idx]:
            idx += 1
            if idx == len(B):
                cnt += 1
                idx = 0
            else:
                continue
        else:
            idx = 0

    print("#{} {}".format(tc, N - M * cnt + cnt))
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: It looks like your example output correctly counts how many times you need to press the key to type "apple". Isn't that what you need?

Comment: The answer to apple is correct, but the answer to the test case that I don't know is not correct.

Comment: Have you checked corner cases? Like empty strings etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what you are missing. This case is failing

```
A,B = "aaaab", "aaab"
```

Your code outputs `5`, but it should be `2`. Think about this a little bit. If you still can't fix your code, I can give more info.

Comment: I tried to modify the code based on the counterexample you gave me, but I still get a fail. Could you help me a little more?

Comment: Can you include your updated code at the end of your post?

Comment: Thank you. I realized that I couldn't solve that problem with the existing code and rewrote it and passed.